# Disabling/hiding slideshow arrows on first/last slides

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using a slideshow based on [w3school's sample](http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_slideshow.asp). I'd like to disable or hide the previous arrow on the first slide and next arrow on the last slide.

I believe I need to edit this JavaScript to include an `if else` clause (if first slide, hide .prev button, else show), but the problem is my lack of understanding. I have a basic understanding of JavaScript, but going deep into the math side (n or i values) is confusing me, and I haven't yet learned jQuery.

```js
function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}
```

Can anyone help me with the code, and also explain what the code would mean in layman's terms?

For easy reference, the code pulled straight from the example is:

```js
 var slideIndex = 1;
showSlides(slideIndex);

function plusSlides(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentSlide(n) {
  showSlides(slideIndex = n);
}

function showSlides(n) {
  var i;
  var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");
  if (n > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1} 
  if (n < 1) {slideIndex = slides.length}
  for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
      slides[i].style.display = "none"; 
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
      dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
  }
  slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block"; 
  dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
/* Slideshow container */
.slideshow-container {
  max-width: 1000px;
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
}

/* Next & previous buttons */
.prev, .next {
  cursor: pointer;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: auto;
  margin-top: -22px;
  padding: 16px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 18px;
  transition: 0.6s ease;
  border-radius: 0 3px 3px 0;
}

/* Position the "next button" to the right */
.next {
  right: 0;
  border-radius: 3px 0 0 3px;
}

/* On hover, add a black background color with a little bit see-through */
.prev:hover, .next:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);
}

/* Caption text */
.text {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 15px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 8px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Number text (1/3 etc) */
.numbertext {
  color: #f2f2f2;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 8px 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

/* The dots/bullets/indicators */
.dot {
  cursor:pointer;
  height: 13px;
  width: 13px;
  margin: 0 2px;
  background-color: #bbb;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  transition: background-color 0.6s ease;
}

.active, .dot:hover {
  background-color: #717171;
}

/* Fading animation */
.fade {
  -webkit-animation-name: fade;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
  animation-name: fade;
  animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}

@keyframes fade {
  from {opacity: .4} 
  to {opacity: 1}
}
```

```html
<div class="slideshow-container">
  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">1 / 3</div>
    <img src="img1.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Text</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">2 / 3</div>
    <img src="img2.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Two</div>
  </div>

  <div class="mySlides fade">
    <div class="numbertext">3 / 3</div>
    <img src="img3.jpg" style="width:100%">
    <div class="text">Caption Three</div>
  </div>

  <a class="prev" onclick="plusSlides(-1)">&#10094;</a>
  <a class="next" onclick="plusSlides(1)">&#10095;</a>
</div>
<br>

<div style="text-align:center">
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(1)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(2)"></span> 
  <span class="dot" onclick="currentSlide(3)"></span> 
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what part of the code you need an explanation for. In general terms it's just adding or substracting from the slide index, adjusting the index when it "overflows" or "underflows" and hiding the slides with a different index.

If you don't want to show first and last arrows you can just add code like

```
var prevArrow = document.getElementsByClassName('prev');
var nextArrow = document.getElementsByClassName('next');
prevArrow[0].style.display = "block";
nextArrow[0].style.display = "block";
if (slideIndex === 1) prevArrow[0].style.display = "none";
if (slideIndex === slides.length) nextArrow[0].style.display = "none";
```

That code just "hides" the "prev arrow when you're in the first slide and the "next" arrow when you're in the last", you can test it in the w3school page and it works. I hope that helps
There's a lot of room for optimization